# How to delete Content Type drop down menu from EditForm.aspx

Tags: content-type, content-editor-web-part, wss-3.0

I am trying to delete Content Type drop down menu from EditForm.aspx but not able to do it?

Any ideas? Pls shoot

-saumil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to get into the DOM and find a good selector for this.  Once you find one, the code should look similar to:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("selector").hide();
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide it with jQuery or you can create a custom list form and hide it that way as well.  Each approach is valid, but the latter is more conducive to performance.  If you are allowed to use SPD, I'd just hide the drop down with a custom list form.

Comment: Thx...Which jQuery code I have to use to hide it?